# Cancellation of pthread seems weird

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, pthread-cleanup

I have a simple test of cancellation of a pthread when assigning this function as a work function:

```
static void * thread_start(void *arg)
{
    printf("New thread started\n");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, NULL);
    pthread_cancel(pthread_self());
    pthread_testcancel();           /* A cancellation point */
    return NULL;
}
```

The cleanup_handler:

```
static void cleanup_handler(void *arg)
{
    printf("Called clean-up handler\n");
}
```

But I get compiler error of some irrelevant syntax error (missing '}' somewhere else). On the other hand, if I add pthread_cleanup_pop(1) like this:

```
static void * thread_start(void *arg)
{
    printf("New thread started\n");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, NULL);
    pthread_cancel(pthread_self());
    pthread_testcancel();           /* A cancellation point */
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);  //added this
    return NULL;
}
```

it compiles and run as expected (pthread_cleanup_pop(1) is not run). The cleanup_handler is executed and thread returns PTHREAD_CANCLED.

It is completely irrelevant to have pthread_cleanup_pop(1) in the end, since all cleanup handlers should always run when a thread is about to be terminated. I don't even care if they are run without my cancellation.

What is wrong?

## SOLVED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html)

> POSIX.1 permits pthread_cleanup_push() and pthread_cleanup_pop() to
>          be implemented as macros that expand to text containing '{' and '}',
>          respectively.  **For this reason, the caller must ensure that calls to
>          these functions are paired within the same function, and at the same
>          lexical nesting level.**  (In other words, a clean-up handler is
>          established only during the execution of a specified section of
>          code.)

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Comment: Yes, thats it, thanks! Now everything makes sense.